# Remove an erroneous email address from iCal invitee list

Tags: macos, ical

I would like to remove an erroneous email address from an event's auto-completion list (via `Add Invitee`) in iCal.

OX S' Mail application provides a `Remove from Previous Recipients List` option,  accessible from a drop-down menu located at the right edge of an email address:

[image]

Is there a way to do so in iCal?  It is important that the solution doesn't remove my existing calendars or events.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know mail and calendar both pull from the same place. If you remove the email address from the previous recipient list in Mail that might fix the problem

Comment: It doesn't seem so, unfortunately. In Mail one can go to `Window > Previous Recipients`. There I don't see the mail addresses in question.

Comment: what happens when you delete the MailRecents file located in: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/AddressBook